# Only Require Authorization for Specific Endpoints in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm new to Spring. I'm here because I tried to implement a POST method and I am getting a 403 forbidden error and I believe it's due to the security filter. I watched a video on implementing Authentication via JWT and the authentication works perfectly fine. However, I believe the security chain exposes all my API endpoints to the security filter. **I only want endpoints denoted with the prefix 'api/v1/auth' to go through the security filter.** The endpoints that only authenticated users can access. Here is my security config.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig{
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Client(withDefaults())
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

This also would affect my ability to implement OAuth2 as I read the endpoint needs to be unauthenticated. I've read other SO posts and the posts are a little dated so I just wanted to see if there was any new solution as what I have seems very similar but still isn't working as intended. All of my APIs are prefixed with api/v1 so I'm not sure if that is causing the problem. All of my other methods are GetMapping so this is the first time I've encountered this error. I've attached the JWT filter and Controller where I encountered the error.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String username;
        if(authHeader == null || authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")){
            filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
            return;
        }
        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        username = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);
        if(username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null){
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if(jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt,userDetails)){
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
    }
}
```

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000/")
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ReviewsController {
    private final ReviewsService reviewsService;
    @PostMapping("/games/reviews")
    public ResponseEntity<Reviews> addGameReviewById(@RequestBody Reviews reviews){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(reviewsService.addGameReviewById(reviews),HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PostMapping("/tech/reviews")
    public ResponseEntity<Reviews> addTechReview(@RequestBody Reviews reviews){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(reviewsService.addTechReview(reviews),HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

[image: Postman Post Request]

Comment: This all seam over complicated. Also I'm surprised that a REST API is configured as OAuth2 client, as well as I am surprised that a client is configured without sessions (where will tokens be stored?). I suggest you have a look at [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials). **Do not skip the OAuth2 essentials section**.

Comment: I would love to know how to simplify it, the tokens are stored in localstorage.

Comment: So, you have read neither the OAuth2 essentials, neither the resource server tutorials. Sad, it would have saved you 2 days.

Answer (score -2):

403 Forbidden indicates Authentication was successful (otherwise would return 401 unauthorized ) but the authenticated user does not have access to the resource, e.g. they don't have the required roles or permissions.

Comment: not only, this could also be missing CSRF token, or CORS or multiple other reasons.

Comment: @praveen Hello, how could this be if I have not set any roles?